# PHP & Android - UTF-8 encoding problems

Tags: php, android, post, encoding

We're doing a POST request via Android to PHP and Android is passing UTF-8 string, our database is currently cp1252 (has a live iPhone backend, hence working with it)

However we can't seem to get the string converted to cp1252. Tried the following code without results

```
$userkey = utf8_decode($userkey);
$userkey = iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1252', $userkey);
$userkey = mb_convert_encoding($userkey, 'cp1252', 'UTF-8');
```

Check the response with

```
echo 'userkey: '.mb_detect_encoding($userkey);
```

Always returns **UTF-8**

Further more if $userkey is sent with value "no" and we do the following

```
if($userkey == "no"){
  echo "not registered"
}else{
  echo "registered find db record"
}
```

The code always seems to drop into **else** - Any help would be great :)

Comment: I think we need some more information here. Could you post at least the HTTP headers, and how you are reading in `$userkey`? Guessing from your last comment, perhaps there are spurious control characters at the end of it?

Comment: Hi Ken - Any suggests to check the spurious control characters at the end?